# Sculpt Mode not appearing

Tags: sculpt

I am fairly new to Blender and have been trying to sculpt things. However, I cannot access Sculpt Mode. It just doesn't appear for me, only Object and Edit Modes. Is there something I'm not doing?

Comment: Also, I can sculpt the first object, but not with any others.

Comment: You can sculpt only mesh objects. Select one in object mode, then try to go to sculpt mode. If you see only edit and object mode you probably selected a curve.

Answer (score 1):

Only Meshes allow for Sculpt mode right now.  Make especially sure that the object selected is a mesh.

Sometimes imported meshes come in as a kind of "meta" object that needs to be converted to a mesh first.  You can convert to a mesh with the corresponding option, it's easy enough to search for with command search: [image: different convert options in the command finder]

Judging by the age of this post, I'm going to say this out loud: are you using Blender 2.87+?  Sculpt mode is a fairly new-ish option for the time.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. managed to solve it by exporting the sculpture with .OBJ and then importing it again into sculpture mode and it worked again. I don't know if this is a bug, but I spent two days looking for the solution and finally found it.

Comment: I was doing some tests and it seems that this error appears when you change the scale of the object in object mode

Answer (score -1):

Note: This is how I got it to work for me.

It's actually very easy.
First get what you're trying to edit and right click.
Then click `Shade Flat`, Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry to be that guy, but this is incorrect advice. Sculpt mode is not locked to the shading method (just tested it for my own sanity). You can access Sculpt mode whilst shaded smooth or flat.
I think the other answer must have been correct but we can't know for sure: only meshes can be taken into Sculpt mode. Perhaps by changing your object to Shade Flat, you selected it in the process and hadn't realised that was the problem.

Comment: I am really new to stackoverflow, So yea, I was probally gonna get that wrong, And I did.

Answer (score -2):

because like no one is anwsering you i'm gonna say a anwser from spikeyxxx on cgcookie. here is what he said:

spikeyxxx
on Jun 22, 2020
You have a Modifier on your Cube. My guess is that that's a Subdivision Surface Modifier. That needs to be applied! There is also a warning in the Modifiers Tab

Comment: Modifiers do not lock out sculpt mode, this is incorrect advice.

Comment: In addition to be unrelated, the solution was given two years and a half ago in the comments. That's a weird way to contribute 

Comment: True, @L0Lock.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀